# Regex for full name with single first/last names

Tags: regex, validation, yup

I am trying to write a regex for Yup for a full name where firstName and lastName are separated by a space and each of them has only one name. For example:

```
First Name
```

and nothing like `My First Name` where `My First`is all considered as a first one. I currently have this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z'\s]*[a-zA-Z'\s]*[a-zA-Z]$/
```

but this will also also allow let's say three names when I only need 2.

Also, no numbers and other special characters should be allowed.

Comment: Then require two words only, `/^\S+\s+\S+$/`

Comment: This will also allow numbers and other expressions, no? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Yes, it will. But will at least allow `ż`, or `Виктор`

Comment: Try: `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+$/`

Answer (score -1):

Try: `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+$/`